# Не работает свойство layout_weight в Андроид

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Учу помаленьку Андройд, и тут вопрос по верстке. Сверстал кнопки по такому типу:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="80dp"  >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" 
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:text="2"
            android:contentDescription="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

        />
        <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" 
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Получилось 4 кнопки с одинаковым размером, т.к. Указан `android:layout_weight="1"`. Вот, после этого я начал изучать стили и сделал стили для кнопок, внешний вид.

```
<style name="calc_digitButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_digit_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#A8A8A8</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>

    </style>
```

Все работает по-прежнему нормально. Все кнопочки ровно. После этого я создаю тему.

```
<style name="CalcTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/calc_digitButton</item>
    </style>
```

И все кнопочки начали придерживаться этого стиля, все супер, НО свойство  `android:layout_weight="1"` перестало работать как положено и стало показываться криво. Началось, после того как я сделал тему. Ниже принтскрин, как криво стали отображается кнопки, но повторюсь, до определения темы все работает нормально.

[image]

Comment: А может просто использовать [gridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)? Есть [пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php).

Comment: ну да, я уже понял, что лоханулся с этим <LinearLayout>. Хотелось бы узнать, в чем тут проблема? Наверно, когда я создаю свою тему, какие-то свойства не наследуются!

Comment: если вы делаете под андроид 4+, то можете использовать более подходящую для ваших целей штуку http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы `layout_weight` работал так, как надо, нужно выставлять размерность, которую будет регулировать weight в 0dp (`android:layout_width` или `android:layout_height`).

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp" 
вот же?

Comment: @duddeniska, что "вот же"?     
android:layout_width="0dp"

так надо